# HTTP error 403 while using role based authorization

Tags: java, spring-security

My project is using JDK 8, Spring Boot 2.7.8 (I'm stuck with Java 8). I am successfully using Google OAuth2 for authentication. Users can log into and out of my site. They even have to authenticate to  get to a `/secure` page and that works.

However, when I try to incorporate role and/or authorities, I can only get HTTP 403 errors. I have a database with groups, users, group_members, etc, just like `JdbcUserDetailsManager` wants, and they're filled with data, as shown below.

[image: Two different users in the database]

How can I get this to work? Below are code snippets.

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSource;

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {
    JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();

    jdbcUserDetailsManager.setDataSource(this.dataSource);

    return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
    HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .cors()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/secure/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)    
            .and()//
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
        .oauth2Login()
            .loginPage(SecurityController.LOGIN_PAGE_MAPPING)//
            .defaultSuccessUrl(SecurityController.LOGIN_SUCCESS_MAPPING)
            .failureUrl("/login-failure-page")
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied-page")
            .and()
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .logoutSuccessUrl(SecurityController.LOGOUT_PAGE_MAPPING).permitAll();

    // For Firefox and h2-console
    http
        .headers()
            .frameOptions().disable();

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

Below are excerpts from the log file.

```
2023-02-24 09:36:57.391 DEBUG 36STXT2 --- [io-8600-exec-10] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2023-02-24 09:36:57.391 DEBUG 36STXT2 --- [nio-8600-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2023-02-24 09:36:57.452 DEBUG 36STXT2 --- [nio-8600-exec-5] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy                 : Securing GET /secure/admin/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_deedf7_1x100.png
2023-02-24 09:36:57.452 DEBUG 36STXT2 --- [nio-8600-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [...], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=..., sub=..., email_verified=true, iss=https://accounts.google.com, given_name=..., locale=en, nonce=..., picture=..., aud=[...apps.googleusercontent.com], azp=...apps.googleusercontent.com, name=..., exp=2023-02-24T18:36:54Z, family_name=..., iat=2023-02-24T17:36:54Z, email=...}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=...], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]]]
2023-02-24 09:36:57.452 DEBUG 36STXT2 --- [nio-8600-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [...], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=..., sub=..., email_verified=true, iss=https://accounts.google.com, given_name=..., locale=en, nonce=..., picture=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AGNmyxZaS0UTnXNuuvQh-HJ6ksu_COG5bFPQj4VZq5X7=s96-c, aud=[411774966392-ct0mr3fbeitc10svg2c3mdotsidprmke.apps.googleusercontent.com], azp=...apps.googleusercontent.com, name=..., exp=2023-02-24T18:36:54Z, family_name=..., iat=2023-02-24T17:36:54Z, email=...}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=...], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]]]
2023-02-24 09:36:57.452 DEBUG 36STXT2 --- [nio-8600-exec-5] o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping        : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-02-24 09:36:57.452 DEBUG 36STXT2 --- [nio-8600-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /secure/admin/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_deedf7_1x100.png] with attributes [hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')]
2023-02-24 09:36:57.453 DEBUG 36STXT2 --- [nio-8600-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl        : Forwarding to /access-denied-page with status code 403
2023-02-24 09:36:57.453 DEBUG 36STXT2 --- [nio-8600-exec-5] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/google-sec-demo/access-denied-page", parameters={}
```

Comment: hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN") is very likely not going to work. Should probably be either hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN") or hasRole('ADMIN"). Update your constant definition or change expression to hasAuthority.

Comment: @ch4mp, I've seen what seems like conflicting advice on how to name authorities and roles. Some say add "ROLE_" to authorities and others say add it to roles. This is my first time playing with Spring Security. But it sounds like I'm on the right track. I've added a picture of what's now in the database.

Comment: for spring a "role" is an "authority" with `ROLE_` prefix => `hasRole("ADMIN")` is strictly the same as `hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")` but **`hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")` expects the user to be granted with `ROLE_ROLE_ADMIN` authority.** In the log you updated, you replaced hasRole with hasAuthority, which is better, but the user is granted with `ROLE_USER` and a few `SCOPE_*` but not `ROLE_ADMIN`...

Comment: As ch4mp said, you are not ADMIN only USER thats why we want full logs, to see these things.

Comment: But those look like Google roles, not mine that are stored in JdbcUserDetailsManager. How do I get my system to use __those__ roles for authorization? The roles in my system are ADMIN and REACTOR. There is no USER role.